# Jqgrid does not showing data

Tags: jqgrid

Please see my js code below

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Home/GetRoles",
        dataType: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['ID', 'Role Name', 'Active'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'RoleId', index: 'RoleId' },
            { key: true, name: 'RoleName', index: 'RoleName' },
             { key: true, name: 'Active', index: 'Active' }
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Roles',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false 
    });
});
```

and output of Get request

```
{"total":2,"page":1,"records":13,"rows":[{"RoleId":1,"RoleName":"Role1","Active":true},{"RoleId":2,"RoleName"
:"Role 2","Active":false},{"RoleId":13,"RoleName":"Role 3","Active":false},{"RoleId":3,"RoleName":"Role
 4","Active":false},{"RoleId":4,"RoleName":"Role 5","Active":false},{"RoleId":5,"RoleName":"Role 6","Active"
:false},{"RoleId":6,"RoleName":"Role 7","Active":false},{"RoleId":7,"RoleName":"Role 8","Active":false
},{"RoleId":8,"RoleName":"Role 9","Active":false},{"RoleId":9,"RoleName":"Role 10","Active":false}]}
```

but grid is always empty

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` should be `datatype: 'json'`, the property `key: true` could be placed only in **one** column. You should remove it from columns `RoleName` and `Active`. Your JSON data contains line feed in the middle of the string `"Role 4"`. Have the JSON data really new line charackter on the place? It would be the error too. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: yes you are right it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix `dataType: 'json'` to `datatype: 'json'`, the property `key: true` could be placed only in one column. You should remove it from columns `RoleName` and `Active`. Your JSON data contains line feed in the middle of the string "`Role 4"`. Have the JSON data really new line character on the place? It would be the error too.

Moreover you should always write the information about the version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The problem existing in one version can not exist in another one. Moreover different version and forks have different options implemented and so to suggest you some workaround one need to know the version and the fork which you use. I develop **free jqGrid** fork, and can recommend you to you the latest version (4.13.0) of jqGrid from the fork.